Powershell script - Get all IP addresses and ports from Network Policy
After a long while im back into powershell and it seems i forgot almost everything. My problem is, how to write a powershell script to get all network policies, all IP addreses and ports, than check all IP addresses on a remote mail server and compare them all.
The reason for this construct is, that IP addresses on the mail server change often and i need to send an email in case this happened so i can edit my network policy. The script should check all IPs and ports in the network policy, list them, than check all IP addresses on the remote mail server and compare them with the entries in the NP and in case IPs changed, send a mail for notification.
So far i tried ()its in a pipeline):
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: Login to <my CaaS Cluster>
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'CaaS'
    namespace: '<my_namespace>'
    command: 'login'
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: NP List
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "List of network policies:"
      kubectl get networkpolicy -n <my_namespace>
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: e-mail server IPs
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "List e-mail server IP addresses."
      nslookup <remote_mail_server>

<namespace1>,<networkpolicyName1>,<port1>,<hostname1>;<namespace2>,<networkpolicyName2>,<port2>,<hostname2>;<namespaceN>,<networkpolicyNameN>,<portN>,<hostnameN>

Format:
hostname:port

